# which is more efficient, select array_agg over partition, or select array (subquery)?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I have data like:

```
 group_id |         day | amount
----------+-------------+-------
        1 | 15 Nov 2015 |   5.0
        1 | 15 Nov 2015 |   6.0
        1 | 14 Nov 2015 |   3.0
        2 | 17 Nov 2015 |   5.0
        2 | 15 Nov 2015 |   5.0
```

and I want to select the top ten amounts for each (group_id, day).  I tried writing things like:

Postgres 9.4

```
select max(x.group_id), max(x.day), max(x.amounts) 
from (select group_id, day, array_agg(amount) over w as amounts,
             row_number() over w as r
      from my_table window w as (partition group_id, day 
                                 order by amount desc)) as x
where x.r<=10 group by x.group_id,x.day
```

It also occurred to me that I could write a much more straightforward query:

```
select a.day, a.group_id, array(select amount 
                                from my_table 
                                where day=a.day and group_id=a.group_id
                                order by amount desc limit 10)
from my_table as a group by a.day, a.group_id
```

Which does exactly what I want.  This led me to the question: assuming I can tweak the first example to get what I want, which query would be faster?  Is the subquery slower than the partitions ?

Comment: Check the execution plans using `explain (analyze, verbose, buffers)`

Comment: I actually just did and was editing my question to say I figured it out with explain analyze.

Comment: what is `row_number() over we as r`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: that's a window function: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have used before, but looks like `over we` was a typo and first time I see the `over` with one alias?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: see the link I posted. Scroll to the bottom of the page

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name other dbms oracle, mssql has that option  as well or is just postgres?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: no idea. It *is* part of the SQL Standard. If you want to know about Microsoft SQL Server you will need read the manual.

Comment: Note: For result sets with 0 rows, `array_agg` returns `NULL`, whereas `ARRAY(subquery)` returns `{}`.

Answer (score 2):

You probably should use an analytic function.

Dont know why you also have MAX, MIN outside the subquery. Your querys doesnt seem to be equivalents.

Your request of top 10 by group should be:

```
WITH ranked as (
      SELECT group_id, 
             day,
             row_number() OVER 
                   (partition by group_id, day ORDER BY ammount DESC) rn
      FROM my_table 
) 
SELECT group_id, 
       day,
       array_agg(amount) over (partition by group_id, day ORDER BY rn)
FROM ranked
WHERE rn <=10
```

Comment: this is not equivalent.  this does not give result in an array of the top ten amounts in order.

Comment: Sorry, but that was not what you ask. You ask for top 10 by group. What about now?